# How to create folder using shell script in android java android studio

Tags: java, android, shell, android-studio

How can I execute shell script in android using java?
This code doesn't work in my project.

Thanks

```
try{
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/su");
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mkdir /folderName");

            InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            is.close();
            process.waitFor();

        } 
        catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: An InputStream to read a folder? No, that will not go. InputStreams are for files.

Comment: It is just to read output like command 'ls -all'.

Comment: Ok. And what does it read?